# Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$ while running job on apache spark 2.0.2 using cassandra connector

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to run simple count on data set from apache spark shell that was previously fetched to my cassandra cluster. To do this I've created simple maven project that creates fat jar, there are my dependencies:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudera.sparkts/sparkts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudera.sparkts</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkts</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm runnig this jar using spark shell using this command:

```
spark-shell --jars Sensors-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar --executor-memory 512M
```

After loading required dependencies I'm trying to run given operation on my spark instance:

```
import pl.agh.edu.kis.sensors._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
val test = new TestConnector(sc)
test.count()
```

This is error I'm receiving:

```
    17/01/21 04:42:37 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "coil_id", "event_time", "car_count", "insert_time" FROM "public"."traffic" WHERE token("coil_id") > ? AND token("coil_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1763)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<init>(TypeConverter.scala:116)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<clinit>(TypeConverter.scala)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:46)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.converterToCassandra(ColumnType.scala:229)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    ... 17 more
17/01/21 04:42:41 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 2
17/01/21 04:42:41 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
17/01/21 04:42:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "coil_id", "event_time", "car_count", "insert_time" FROM "public"."traffic" WHERE token("coil_id") > ? AND token("coil_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1763)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:46)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.converterToCassandra(ColumnType.scala:229)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    ... 17 more
17/01/21 04:42:45 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 3
17/01/21 04:42:45 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
17/01/21 04:42:45 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "coil_id", "event_time", "car_count", "insert_time" FROM "public"."traffic" WHERE token("coil_id") > ? AND token("coil_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1763)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:46)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.converterToCassandra(ColumnType.scala:229)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    ... 17 more
```

And here's my code:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.rdd.CassandraTableScanJavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 20.01.2017.
 */
public class TestConnector {

    SparkContext sc;

    public TestConnector(SparkContext context){
        sc = context;
        sc.conf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","10.156.207.84")
                .set("spark.cores.max","1");
    }

    public TestConnector(){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","10.156.207.84")
                .set("spark.cores.max","1");
        sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    }

    public void count(){
        CassandraTableScanJavaRDD rdd  = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("public","traffic");
        System.out.println("Total readings: " + rdd.count());
    }

}
```

Scala version: 2.11.8,
Spark version: 2.0.2,
Cassandra version: 3.9,
Java version: 1.8.0_111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you are running into looks like a Scala Version mismatch. The Default installation of Spark 2.0 uses Scala 2.11 but you have specified 2.10 for all of your dependencies. Change all the `_2.10` to `_2.11`

Next you will run into a Guava Mismatch problem because you are including the Cassandra Driver when you should not be. So remove the dependency on the Java driver.

See
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#how-do-i-fix-guava-classpath-errors

Answer (score 0):

just ensure your build.sbt file is like this :

```
name := "sink-to-aggs"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.10"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.3"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.5")
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.5"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

spark cassandra datastax driver only works with 2.0.0 spark