# Error thrown while reading data from cassandraTable

Tags: cassandra, pyspark

I am trying to read data from cassandra table using `pyspark-cassandra connector`.
I downloaded the package from [pyspark-cassandra](https://spark-packages.org/package/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra)

My script is as follow:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

import pyspark_cassandra
from pyspark_cassandra import CassandraSparkContext,Row

conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("App1").set("spark.cassandra.co nnection.host","http://192.168.0.2")

sc = CassandraSparkContext(conf=conf)


rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace1", "table1")
```

When I run above script using command:

```
 $ bin/spark-submit --packages TargetHolding:pyspark-cassandra:0.3.5 pyscript.py
```

I am getting below error:

```
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling  
> o83.newInstance. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
> initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$
```

Comment: I tried to run above script in terminal. There's no error while importing the packages. The error I'm getting is on 

      rdd=sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","table")

Comment: Hi, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775862/could-not-initialize-class-com-datastax-spark-connector-types-typeconverter-whi) it might be a scala version mismatch issue between spark and the cassandra package, could you please check that? (The 0.3.5 version you are including is using scala 2.10 from what I can see)

Comment: why host is using `http`?

Comment: @undefined_variable I tried removing http but same result

Comment: @mkaran I am using pyspark-cassandra-connector not spark-cassandra-connector, still I need to change scala version? and how? I can't see anything in pyspark-cassandra to change scala version.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar the pyspark-cassandra-connector uses scala 2.10, you need to check your spark installation for the scala version, either 2.10 or 2.11. Run in your terminal: `spark-submit --version` and it will show you the scala version too.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar  If there is a mismatch, since the connector uses 2.10 and not 2.11 you either should use a different connector that supports 2.11 or a different version of pyspark

Comment: @mkaran The scala version for spark is 2.11.8 where connector using 2.11.6(For connector I checked scala version in target folder and .xml file).